# Fermat's Little Theorem & Chinese Remainder Theorem Problem

Tags: proof-writing, chinese-remainder-theorem, carmichael-numbers

Prove that for any positive integer $a,$ $a^{561} \equiv a \pmod{561}.$

All I got so far is by Fermat's Little Theorem,

$a^{3} \equiv a \pmod{3}$

$a^{11} \equiv a \pmod{11}$

$a^{17} \equiv a \pmod {17}$

Is there a way to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem on this problem?

Comment: Yes,  $a^{561}\equiv a\bmod 3, 11, $ and $17, $ so $\bmod561$

Comment: Can you elaborate how do you prove that

Comment: See below; by the way, this means $561$ is a [Carmichael number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) (it is the smallest one)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof by induction that $a^{17+16n}\equiv a\bmod 17$.

Base case:  $a^{17}\equiv a\bmod 17$ (Fermat's little theorem).

Inductive step:  assume $a^{17+16(n-1)}\equiv a\bmod17$.

Then $a^{17+16n}\equiv a^{16}a^{17+16(n-1)}\equiv a^{16}a=a^{17}\equiv a\bmod17.\square$

Similarly, $a^{11+10n}\equiv a\bmod11$ and $a^{3+2n}\equiv a\bmod3$.

Therefore, $a^{561}\equiv a\bmod 3, 11, $ and $17$,

so by the Chinese remainder theorem $a^{561}\equiv a\pmod {3\times11\times17=561}$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach.

Tool: $s | (bc)$ and $s$ relatively prime to $b$ implies that $s | c.$

Let $c \equiv (a^{(561)} - a).$ 
It is assumed that $3 | c, \;11 | c, \;17 | c.$

$3 | c \;\Rightarrow\; \exists k_1 \,\in \,\mathbb{Z} \;\ni
c = 3 \times k_1.$

Using the tool, this means that since $11$ is relatively prime
to $3,$ 
and since $11 | c = 3 \times k_1,$ 
then $11 | k_1.$

This means that $\exists k_2 \,\in \,\mathbb{Z} \;\ni
k_1 = 11 \times k_2.$

Similarly, since $17 | c = (3 \times 11) \times k_2 = 33 \times k_2,$ 
and since $17$ is relatively prime to $33,$ 
$17 | k_2$.

This means that $\exists k_3 \,\in \,\mathbb{Z} \;\ni
k_2 = 17 \times k_3.$

Thus, 
$c = (3 \times k_1) = (3 \times 11 \times k_2)$ 
$= (3 \times 11 \times 17 \times k_3) = 561 \times k_3.$

Thus, $561 | c.$